# I'd like to understand how a windows smart quote turns into "â€™"

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, ms-word

Here's the workflow:

1. user types in Word; Word changes a single apostrophe to a "smart quote"
2. user pastes the test from word into a form on a web page; the page the form is in is encoded in UTF-8
3. the data gets saved into a MySQL database with the encoding `latin1`
4. when retrieved from the database by a PHP app (which assumes the database encoding is UTF-8) and displayed in a UTF-8 web page, the quote displays as â€™

I realise there's a mismatch between the encoding of the input and output pages and the database. That I'm going to fix.

Shouldn't the character survive the trip to and from the database anyway?

And how does a single character (0x92 if I'm not confused) go through that process and come out the other end as three characters?

Can someone talk me through what's happening to the bytes at each stage of the process?

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: @deceze: Thanks for linking to your article! I didn't know it before, and it's the perfect references for questions like these.

Comment: Yes, good article, although at first I was confused by the name being so close to Joel's more famous one. Yours is more practical!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Step 1:**

Word converts `'` to `’` (Unicode codepoint `U+2019`, `RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK`).

**Step 2:**

`’` is encoded into UTF-8 as `E2 80 99`

**Step 3**:

This appears to be where the problem occurs. It looks like the UTF-8 string is stored *without conversion* in the latin-1-encoded MySQL field:

`E2 80 99` in latin-1 is `â€™`.

**Step 4:**

Either here or in the previous step, that falsely used latin-1 string is converted to UTF-8.

`â€™` in UTF-8 is `C3 A2 E2 82 AC E2 84 A2`.

This will display on a UTF-8-encoded website as `â€™`.

Comment: According to http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html we're dealing with E2 80 99 and RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK but that's just for the record.

Comment: You've left me with a couple of questions over where exactly conversions happen. Does modern Word use UTF-8 internally, or does it use 1252, and the browser converts on paste? But I believe the answer to you your "either here or in the previous step" is "here". If I get the information out via Perl and DBI without saying which encoding to expect, no problem. The problematic "conversion" happens with a PHP script which *expects* UTF-8.

Comment: @AmbroseChapel: Thanks for spotting the mistake! Now of course I don't know what Word does internally. I would assume that it uses Unicode. Not sure in what encoding, if any, Unicode code points are copied into the clipboard, but I suppose Windows would handle these things transparently.

Comment: In step 2 you are actually printing the left single quotation mark.

Comment: @Roland: Oops. Thanks for noticing :)

Comment: UTF-8 std recommends no BOM char, but Microsoft includes it when files are saved as UTF-8 in Notepad.  So Notepad probably tries to read your UTF-8 file as Latin-1/CP1252 since it does not have a BOM (BOM is used to know endianness which should be a non-issue in UTF-8).  Notepad is NOT "plain text" (which BTW is not even universally defined, but don't tell your manager that)--you CAN paste in a smart quote and save it as such (an illegal char, 0x93, very close to XOFF and as such very bad)